# Can I alter and edit an image with the Cloudinary SDK before I upload it and save it to their server?

Tags: angular, image, cloudinary

Currently I'm using Cloudinary.com to save my users images. I know how to do some of the transformations on the image url (ex. f_auto, q_auto, w_xx, c_scale, etc) but this is after I've uploaded it and saved it as an asset and have the url to the image on their server.

**QUESTION** - I would like to edit my image (brightness, contrast, crop, zoom, rotate) as soon as the user loads it onto my site and before I upload it to Cloudinary. Can I do this with the Cloudinary SDk? Is it done right on the browser or is there some temporary place on their server where it can get saved, while it's being edited by my user?

FYI - I've only found this as a resource in their docs, but there is a not above it that says "Note This step assumes that you have assets already uploaded in your account."

[Cloudinary link](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/angular_quick_start#2_add_cloudinary_to_your_code)

Answer (score 0):

When using Cloudinary Programmable Media, its workflow requires the assets to be uploaded first before the transformations can be applied. And in your use case, you may need to manage the assets within your custom code before uploading the final asset to your Cloudinary Media Library.

Alternatively, you could also explore the [Media Editor Widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/media_editor) and see if it can fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The widget won't work for me as I have a custom UI for the users. I'm trying to weigh my options here and trying to see if Cloudinary will fit my need, otherwise I'll try and use Toast UI editor or something else to do crop, brightness, contrast, zoom, etc. I need something for Angular but not having much luck finding anything. Toast UI has a JS library, but I'm a little scared to try and use it in my Angular app